# What would the system do when FIN is recv while there's still data in socket send buffer?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

Currently I am suffering from a strange problem.

So I am wondering what will be happened.

Say there's a TCP connection and the socket send buffer has 10 bytes of data, then a FIN is recv, which of the packets will be replied?

A. an ACK with 10 bytes of data

B. an ACK with none of byte and an other ACK with 10 bytes

C. either of above

Comment: One good way to find out would be to run `tcpdump` on the exact system in question and observe what it does.  You could force a situation like this by sending aggressively and having the other side receive slowly then close the connection.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

A FIN means only that the other side will not send anymore data. It does not mean that it will not accept more data and thus the connection will not be closed by the local system. This means that the ACK to the FIN will reflect the current state of the connection: if the data can be send (depends on the window) the local system will usually(*) send a packet containing the data and the ACK for the FIN. If the data can not be send immediately it will only ACK the FIN and maybe later send the data.

(*) Note that it can do the sending in two packets in theory but TCP stacks usually combine data and ACK if possible so that less packets are send.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I am suffering from a strange problem.

I suggest you should post the actual strange problem, instead of your guesswork about it.

> A. an ACK with 10 bytes of data

*What* 10 bytes of data? Why would an ACK echo 10 bytes of received data?

> B. an ACK with none of byte and an other ACK with 10 bytes

This doesn't makes sense either.

> C. either of above

Nor does this.

When a FIN is received it should be acknowledged via an ACK packet. As the FIN terminates the connection in this direction, the amount of data currently in the socket receive buffer is irrelevant.

Comment: The 10 bytes data is in the send buffer of the socket of the machine that recv FIN.